# how to make a deep_slice in a hash on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash-of-hashes

I was looking around for a clean way to do this and I found some workarounds but did not find anything like the slice (some people recommended to use a gem but I think is not needed for this operations, pls correct me if I am wrong), so I found myself with a hash that contains a bunch of hashes and I wanted a way to perform the [Slice](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) operation over this hash and get also the key/value pairs from nested hashes, so the question:

Is there something like deep_slice in ruby?

**Example:**

```
input: a = {b: 45, c: {d: 55, e: { f: 12}}, g: {z: 90}}, keys = [:b, :f, :z]

expected output: {:b=>45, :f=>12, :z=>90}
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around for a while I decided to implement this myself, this is how I fix it:

```rb
a = {b: 45, c: {d: 55, e: { f: 12}}, g: {z: 90}}
keys = [:b, :f, :z]
def custom_deep_slice(a:, keys:)
    result = a.slice(*keys)
    a.keys.each do |k|
        if a[k].class == Hash
            result.merge! custom_deep_slice(a: a[k], keys: keys)
        end
    end
    result
end
c_deep_slice = custom_deep_slice(a: a, keys: keys)
p c_deep_slice
```

The code above is a classic [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which takes advantage of the [merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge) provided by the hash class.

You can test the code above [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby?v2=1)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'set'

def recurse(h, keys)
  h.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),arr|
    if keys.include?(k)
      arr << [k,v]
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
      arr.concat(recurse(v,keys))
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
hash = { b: 45, c: { d: 55, e: { f: 12 } }, g: { b: 21, z: 90 } }
keys = [:b, :f, :z]
```

```
arr = recurse(hash, keys.to_set)
  #=> [[:b, 45], [:f, 12], [:b, 21], [:z, 90]]
```

Notice that `hash` differs slightly from the example hash given in the question. I added a second nested key `:b` to illustrate the problem of returning a hash rather than an array of key-value pairs. Were we to convert `arr` to a hash the pair `[:b, 45]` would be discarded:

```
arr.to_h
  #=> {:b=>21, :f=>12, :z=>90}
```

If desired, however, one could write:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[k] ||= []) << v }
  #=> {:b=>[45, 21], :f=>[12], :z=>[90]}
```

I converted `keys` from an array to a set merely to speed lookups (`keys.include?(k)`).

A slightly modified approach could be used if the hash contained nested arrays of hashes as well as nested hashes.

Comment: This is a good answer @Cary Swoveland although not the behavior I expect/need from my case/ slice, but good indeed,  thx for the response 

Comment: I don't understand. How does the behaviour differ from what you want?

Comment: I am talking about the second case (the arrays), the first one is the expected, and as I said above it is a pretty good approach 

Comment: I want to have only one value for :b for example, and the internal value (the one more deep takes precedence), that is why I merged in that order, but that is just for my use case

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to clarify the problem. Can you explain when `arr.to_h` would not provide the desired result? Actually, if there are duplicate keys your method does not necessary give precedence to the most deeply-nested one. For example, if `a = {b: 45, c: {d: 55, e: { f: 12}, z: 0}, g: {f: 90}}`, the return value is `{:b=>45, :z=>0, :f=>90}`, yet `:f=>12` is more deeply-nested.

Comment: I never said that arr.to_h does not provide the desire results, only that in the second case I don't want to have multiple values, your approach as I mentioned above is good and indeed the first one produces the result and by nested (maybe I miscommunicate I mean last one, but again that is for my use case)

Comment: Actually, I upvoted your answer because is useful otherwise I wouldn't upvote

Answer (score 0):

My version

maybe it should help

```rb
def deep_slice( obj, *args )
    deep_arg = {}
    slice_args = []
    args.each do |arg|
        if arg.is_a? Hash
            arg.each do |hash|
                key, value = hash
                if obj[key].is_a? Hash
                    deep_arg[key] = deep_slice( obj[key], *value ) 
                elsif obj[key].is_a? Array
                    deep_arg[key] = obj[key].map{ |arr_el| deep_slice( arr_el, *value) }
                end
            end
        elsif arg.is_a? Symbol
            slice_args << arg
        end
    end
    obj.slice(*slice_args).merge(deep_arg)
end
```

Object to slice

```rb
obj = {
  "id": 135,
  "kind": "transfer",
  "customer": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin",
  },
  "array": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "TEST",
            "more_deep": {
                "prop": "first",
                "prop2": "second"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "name": "2222"
        }
    ]
}
```

Schema to slice

```rb
deep_slice(
    obj,
    :id,
    customer: [
        :name
    ],
    array: [
        :name,
        more_deep: [
            :prop2
        ]
    ]
)
```

Result

```rb
{
    :id=>135, 
    :customer=>{
        :name=>"Admin"
    }, 
    :array=>[
        {
         :name=>"TEST", 
         :more_deep=>{
            :prop2=>"second"
         }
        }, 
        {
            :name=>"2222"
        }
    ]
}
```